# Tab Bar Controller within Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, xcode8

I am trying to figure out a way to make a tab bar controller within a tab bar view.
Basically, if the initial tab bar controller links to tab1, tab2, and tab3, I want a tab bar to exist within tab1 that branches out to Day1, Day2, and Day3.
So far I've been failing, and I'm wondering if it's programmatically possible.

The tab bar in tab1 has to be at the top, too, and does that mean I need a custom tab bar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a tab bar at the top, you will need to create one on your own. I believe you can just add in a NavigationController and link it to a ViewController so that the view controller has a nav bar at the top. You could then just add UIBarButtonItems that link to different TabBarControllers where the tabs would be on the bottom.